# How to set alpha for an Assets Color in Swift

Tags: swift, assets, uicolor

I just wanted to know how to change the opacity (alpha) of an asset color I have. When I try this `UIColor(named: "something", alpha: 0.4)`, Xcode complains: `Extra argument 'alpha' in call`.

Is there any way I can modify the opacity of an asset color programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIColor`, as mentioned by Jasur S., has the [`withAlphaComponent(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621922-withalphacomponent).

It can be used with any `UIColor` objects to modify its `alpha`:

```swift
let color = UIColor(named: "something")?.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Creating custom extensions to cover existing functionality is an arguable good.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this extension for `UIColor` and easy to use.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(named: String, alpha: CGFloat) {
        if let rgbComponents = UIColor(named: named)?.cgColor.components {
            self.init(red: rgbComponents[0], green: rgbComponents[1], blue: rgbComponents[2], alpha: alpha)
        } else {
            self.init(named: named)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let colorWithAlpha = UIColor(named: "Assets Color", alpha: 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set color alpha component when you assign color as follows:

```
button.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can modify asset color from here
Select that particular asset color and
Drag that opacity indicator in left or right or directly set some values

Comment: Can I do it programmatically?

Comment: In SwiftUI we can do programmatically like this                   ".foregroundColor(.accentColor).opacity(0.3)"
Let me check in swift and will update you for the same

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension to get the rgb value from the UIColor

```
extension UIColor {
    var rgba: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        return (red, green, blue, alpha)
    }
}
```

Then you can create a new color

```
let assetColor = UIColor(named: "something")
let (r,g,b,_) = assetColor.rgba
let newColor = UIColor(red:r, green:g, blue:b, alpha: 0.4)
```

Comment: Looks promising! Please give me a minute or so to check it...